# Linux shell script how to use the same output for second operation

Tags: linux

This script has been create to backup files 24 hours before from now (midnight crontab), but my concern is, while the first tar is being created (first find) a lot of "" files are being created, so when the second find is executed, it would remove more files than the first one, so the removed files would be more than the backed up.

***Script edited on February 4th 2014, focus on loop for removing the listed files on temp file***

```
    #!/bin/sh
    DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
    LOCATION=/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/
    FILE="cdr_backup_${DATE}.tar.gz"
    TEMPFILE="tempfile_${DATE}"
    ERROR="Error:Tar file not created nor removed the source call records"
    cd "${LOCATION}"
    find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print > ${TEMPFILE}
    tar -czf ${FILE} -T ${TEMPFILE}
    if [ -f $FILE ];
    then

            number=$(more ${TEMPFILE} |wc -l)
            echo "$DATE:Number of files backed up-->$number ">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
            while IFS= read -r line
            do
                rm -f $line
            done < "${TEMPFILE}"
    else
            echo "$DATE:$ERROR">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
    fi
```

Is there a way to ensure that the same source backed up is removed ? maybe using 'xargs' ?

thanks in advance for your valuable help

Answer (score 0):

If you have enough space firstly move found files into a work folder then remove the work folder after backup.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you run `find` twice. Between the first invocation and the second anything could happen.

Do something like this instead:

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
FILE="cdr_backup_${DATE}.tar.gz"
DESTINATION=/root/patrick_temp/
ERROR="Tar file has not been created nor removed the source call records"

BACKUP_FILES=$(find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print)
tar -czvf ${FILE} ${BACKUP_FILES}
if [ -f $FILE ];
then
    mv cdr_backup* ${DESTINATION}
    rm -rf ${BACKUP_FILES}
else
    echo $ERROR 
fi
```

If you might have *LOTS* of files to backup you can write the file names to a temp file, use that file for the tar invocation, and then use a loop to remove all of the files listed in the temp file.

EDIT based on your recent update.

```
#!/bin/sh
DATE=`date '+%Y%m%d'`
LOCATION=/home/see/rbirun/send/VPN/Mobile/
FILE="cdr_backup_${DATE}.tar.gz"
# use mktemp to make the temp file. This is more secure and better practice.
TEMPFILE=$(mktemp)  # --tmpdir lets you place the created temp file wherever you need it
ERROR="Error:Tar file not created nor removed the source call records"

cd "${LOCATION}"

find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print > ${TEMPFILE}

tar -czf ${FILE} -T ${TEMPFILE}

# first, cleanup temps

# no need for `more` here. Also, `cat` is more typically used when this is needed
number=$(wc -l ${TEMPFILE})  
echo "$DATE:Number of files backed up-->$number ">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
for line in $(cat ${TEMPFILE})
do
    rm -f $line
done
rm ${TEMPFILE}

# now process activity

if [ ! -f $FILE ];
then
    echo "$DATE:$ERROR">>log_after_cdr_backup.txt
    exit 1
fi
```

I hope this settles your questions.

Comment: hi Sean, thanks for your useful reply, i was facing the tar "too many arguments problem" so i needed to use the temporal file, but it is not working for my, is this the way?
`code` find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print > archivo_temporal
tar -czvf ${FILE} archivo_temporal `code`

Comment: Sean Many thanks now it is running as expected when executed manually but not in crontab (im using SUSE 10 SP2)

Comment: When cron runs if there is any output it is mailed to whoever owns the crontab. It may be root or it may be the user. Check there for more info. Two likely possibilities are permissions and running under the wrong shell.

Comment: Hi Sean, i finally get it work, but i need to delete the source files which are in the temp file created using -T option, what is the way to deleted the files referenced on this temp file?
`TEMPFILE="tempfile_${DATE}" `
`find . -name 'VPN_CALLRECORD*' -type f -ctime 1 -print > ${TEMPFILE}`
`tar -czf ${FILE} -T ${TEMPFILE}`
is this the way ?
`rm "${TEMPFILE}"`

Comment: I edit the complete script above so you can have a good view of this point, according to your suggestion i would need a loop to remove the files listed in the temp file like this way ?
`for f in $TEMPFILE
do
 rm "$f"
done`

Comment: Hi @Sean Perry, please check above the edited script, im not sure if this loop sintax is ok:
`while IFS= read -r line
            do
                rm -f $line
            done < "${TEMPFILE}"`